# Can we break the pre-defined prototype chain of Numbers, Strings, Boolean, Arrays in JS Manually or Reassign Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, prototype-chain

When, we make a new variable of type number (say num1), its `__proto__` points to `Number Object`. The `__proto__` of it, will again point to `Object Core`, its `__proto__` points to `null`, thereby ending the Prototype-chain.

What I am trying to do, is override this chain in middle, by trying to change the `__proto__` link from `Number Object` to some string. I cannot do the break in chain, as after my assignment its still pointing to `Object Core` structure.

Am I doing something wrong to break this prototype chain OR is it impossible to break the pre-defined prototype chain in browser!

```
Number.__proto__ = "abc"; 
let num4 = 8;
console.log(num4.__proto__);//returns Number Object
console.log(num4.__proto__.__proto__)//should return string "abc"
```

**Output:**

[image]

However, I know I can add certain item in the middle of chain (like in Number-Object) by following code:

```
Number.prototype.alpha = "def";
let num5 = 99; 
console.log(num5.__proto__);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This seems like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Whatever you're trying to achieve here, there's almost certainly a better way to do it than modifying the prototypes of built-ins or the prototype chains of built-ins.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Yes, bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Modifying the built-in prototypes of fundamental objects, or the built-in prototype chains, is a *very bad idea* in the general case. I strongly recommend not doing it.

`Number.__proto__` is the prototype of the `Number` function, **not** the prototype for `Number` objects (which is `Number.prototype`).

Also, JavaScript has both number primitives and Number objects. Most of the time, you're dealing with a number primitive. When you use properties (including methods) on a number primitive (`n = 42`) such as like `toString`, the JavaScript engine gets those from `Number.prototype` even though `n` is a primitive.

You *can* change the prototype of `Number.prototype`. For instance, you can set it to `null` so that `Number` objects no longer inherit from anything but `Number.prototype` (breaking the link with `Object.prototype`), meaning property lookup on a number primitive doesn't find properties and methods from `Object.prototype` anymore:

```js
const n = 8;
console.log(typeof n.hasOwnProperty);           // function
console.log(Object(n) instanceof Number);       // true
console.log(Object(n) instanceof Object);       // true
Object.setPrototypeOf(Number.prototype, null);
console.log(typeof n.hasOwnProperty);           // undefined
console.log(Object(n) instanceof Number);       // true
console.log(Object(n) instanceof Object);       // false
```

(`Object(n)` returns a `Number` object for the number primitive `n`. I used it there because `instanceof` is always `false` for primitives [`n instanceof Number` is `false`, for instance]. To check inheritance, we need an object temporarily.)

As you can see, the link between `Number` objects and `Object` has been broken.

**Again, this is a very bad idea in the general case, as it will tend to break things. Just because we *can* do it doesn't mean we *should*.**

> However, I know I can add certain item in the middle of chain (like in Number-Object) by following code:
>
> ```
> Number.prototype.alpha = "def";
> let num5 = 99; 
> console.log(num5.__proto__);
> ```

That's just adding a property to `Number.prototype`, not inserting something into the prototype chain. But it's possible to insert into the prototype chain, too, since we can change the prototype of `Number.prototype`:

```js
function Custom() {
}
// Change `Custom.prototype` to an object whose prototype
// is the prototype of `Number.prototype` (which will be
// `Object.prototype` in an unsullied environment).
// (`Object.create` creates an object setting its prototype
// to the given object.)
Object.defineProperty(Custom, "prototype", {
    value: Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(Number.prototype)),
    writable: true,
});
Object.defineProperty(Custom.prototype, "constructor", {
    value: Custom,
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
});
Object.defineProperty(Custom.prototype, "example", {
    value() {
        return "hi there";
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
});
Object.setPrototypeOf(Number.prototype, Custom.prototype);

const n = 8;
console.log(n.example());                 // "hi there"
console.log(Object(n) instanceof Custom); // true
```

I used a constructor function there just so we could readily use `instanceof` to check inheritance, but you can insert a prototype without a constructor function. Here's that same code without one:

```js
const custom = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(Number.prototype));
Object.defineProperty(custom, "example", {
    value() {
        return "hi there";
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
});
Object.setPrototypeOf(Number.prototype, custom);

const n = 8;
console.log(n.example()); // "hi there"
```

---

**Note 1:** *Changing* the prototype of an existing objects (e.g., with `Object.setPrototypeOf`) is best avoided. JavaScript engines optimize on the assumption (which is normally true) that the prototype of an object won't change once it's been created. Changing it breaks that assumption, which removes those optimizations from the object.

**Note 2:** You'll notice I didn't use the [`__proto__` accessor property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) anywhere above. It's deprecated and should not be used in new code, use [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) and (if absolutely necessary) [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) instead. It would also fail for any object that doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype`, since that's where the `__proto__` accessor property is defined.