# Difference between __proto__ and [[prototype]] in Global-Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

In Browser there are some Global-Objects pre-built (Objects, String, Number, Date, etc). Mother of all such global-objects is "Object". As, this Object is the prototype of nearly all of the data-types present in JS (except only 2 - null and undefined).

Now, we move up after creating any variable of any data-type, we'll use `__proto__` to climb up the chain. But, when we react the "Object", the `__proto__` points to null and "prototype-chain" has an ending!

Till now I thought `prototype` and `__proto__` are one and the same.
Today, I went and found, that in the `Global-Object`, while `__proto__` points to null,`[[prototype]]` (inside get **proto** & set **proto**) consists of heaps of other values.

Can someone differentiate to me, what exactly is the difference between `__proto__` and `[[prototype]]` and why the values inside both are completely different? While I thought both things are 1 and the same!

[image]

I also read this: [Difference between __proto__ and [[ Prototype ]] in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69506771/difference-between-proto-and-prototype-in-javascript) but got more confused as it says `__proto__ === [[prototype]]` but then says something of internal-slot? Now, can I get a simple clear answer?

Also, if the `__proto__` is `null`, how then `get __proto__` fetch any result? --isn't this absurd? It will fetch result, only if the any value is there, and not `null`.

Comment: *"Till now I thought `prototype` and `__proto__` are one and the same."* Please clarify that. Do you mean you thought `Object.prototype` and `Object.__proto__` were the same?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Yes for anything, like `Array.__proto__` and `Array's [[prototype]]`, or for that matter same for anything like Date, String, Promise, Number, etc.

Comment: How about this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript

Comment: @Deadpool - That doesn't answer my question. Are you talking about `Array.prototype` and `Array.__proto__`? (**Not** `[[Prototype]]`)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder -  I think now there are 3 items - `Array.prototype`, `Array.__proto__`, and `[[prototype]]`. I thought all 3 were just the same.

Comment: The `[[prototype]]` you mark in the screen shot is not of the main object, but of the setter **function**. That is a different object!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/572996/1169519

Comment: @Deadpool - Correct, there are three things. And no, they aren't all the same.

Comment: @trincot - But, prototype always refers to `next object that is parent and linked`, There is no setter object in this `prototype chain`. For eg, `let obj1 = new Object()`. obj1.__proto__ points to Global-Object, obj1.__proto__.__proto__ points to null. Where is *setter function* in this chain?

Comment: It is there: `set __proto__: f` .... the `f` tells you this `__proto__` property is a *function* and the `set` keyword indicates that it is a *setter* (look up getters & setters). So as long as the setter is not **called**, we are looking at a function. And functions are objects with their own properties that have nothing to do with the object on which they are a property. Although we use getters and setters as if they are plain properties, they are not: they are implemented as functions (a getter and a setter). In the screenshot you see the properties of those **functions**, not of the proto.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you've said:

> I think now there are 3 items - `Array.prototype`, `Array.__proto__`, and `[[prototype]]`. I thought all 3 were just the same.

*(`[[Prototype]]` is usually capitalized.)*

That's the fundamental misunderstanding (that and looking at the wrong part of the console output; more below). They aren't. Here's what they are:

1. `[[Prototype]]` is the name of the internal field of an object that says what that object's prototype is.
2. `__proto__` is an accessor property defined by `Object.prototype` that exposes the `[[Prototype]]` internal field. As [I've told you before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70967680/157247), it's deprecated. Use `Object.getPrototypeOf` and (if you can't avoid it) `Object.setPrototypeOf`.
3. `SomeConstructorFunction.prototype` is a property on `SomeConstructorFunction` that refers to an object. If you create an object via `new SomeConstructorFunction` (or an equivalent operation), the object that `SomeConstructorFunction.prototype` refers to is set as the `[[Prototype]]` of the new object.

See also the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript).

> In Browser there are some Global-Objects pre-built (Objects, String, Number, Date, etc). Mother of all such global-objects is "Object". As, this Object is the prototype of nearly all of the data-types present in JS (except only 2 - null and undefined).

No, `Object` is a function. `Object.prototype` is the mother of all objects — except the ones it isn't, because it's possible for an object not to inherit from it (or indeed, from anything). `Object.create(null)` creates an object with no prototype object.

> Can someone differentiate to me, what exactly is the difference between `__proto__` and `[[prototype]]` and why the values inside both are completely different?

They aren't (but keep reading). In the picture you've shown, you're looking at `[[Prototype]]` on a **function**, the setter of the `__proto__` accessor property. You're not looking at `[[Prototype]]` on the same thing you're looking at `__proto__` on.

In your picture you're basically looking at `Object.prototype` (because you're looking at `__proto__` on the result of `new Object`). Chrome's devtools don't show the `[[Prototype]]` internal field of `Object.prototype` (surprisingly), but it they did it would be `null` [per specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-properties-of-the-object-prototype-object).

Let's instead look at a simple object:

[image: devtools screenshot of the text below]

```
>  const obj1 = {example: "x"};
<- undefined
>  obj1
<- {example: 'x'}
      example: "x"
      [[Prototype]]: Object
>  Object.getPrototypeOf(obj1) === Object.prototype
<- true
>  Object.getPrototypeOf(obj1) === obj1.__proto__
<- true
>  obj1.prototype
<- undefined
```

(One part of that which could be confusing is where is says `[[Prototype]]: Object`. The devtools show the name of the constructor for an object. The `[[Prototype]]` of the object is the object referenced by `Object.prototype`, not the `Object` constructor itself.)

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot you shared, you compare two things that are unrelated.

The first box shows the value you get from accessing `__proto__`. It is indeed `null`. But realise that this value is retrieved by calling the **getter**. `__proto__` is not a plain property, it is implemented using a getter and setter. This means that when you write:

```
var a = x.__proto__;
```

... a function is called. This is the `get __proto__` function. This function is a method that is defined in the prototype chain of `x` (it is actually defined on `Object.prototype`).

Similarly if you write:

```
x.__proto__ = a;
```

...a function is called. This is the `set __proto__` function.

The second box in your screenshot shows the properties of this `set __proto__` function object. Remember that functions are objects too. And that object has little to do with the main object of your screenshot.

You can also access the definitions of these getter and setter functions with the following script:

```js
let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, "__proto__");

console.log(descriptor);
```